# How to remove the particular row borders in table widget using pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Here i have a sample code,in that i need to remove the borders of the particular rows in table widget.i tried many ways but i couldn't find any method.Can any one please tell me how can i remove the border of the table widget.I used gridlayout(False)but this method is used for to  remove the all border of the table.please help me.Thank you in advance.

given below is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys, collections
from functools import partial
class Inventory_items(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Inventory_items, self).__init__(parent)
        print "hello inventory"
        # self.showFullScreen()
        self.inventory_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.inventory_widget.show()
        self.inventory_widget.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: black;color: white;}")
        self.inventory_dict = {"Shirt": {"Men Solid Formal Blue shirt": ["10.10.1(Red)","10.10.2(blue)"],"Unit:Quantity": ["10", "5"],"Discount:0%": ["300", "400"]},
        "Frocks":{"Unit:Quantity":["50","30"],"Baby Girls Partywear Frock":["10.10.1(pink)","10.10.1(black)"],"Discount:0%": ["900", "1200"]},"Shoes":{"Unit:Quantity":["100","300"],"Sparx Men's Running Shoes":["Navy Blue","Orange color"],"Discount:0%": ["2000", "2500"]},"Phones":{"Unit:Quantity":["30","10"],"Realme 2 Pro Smart phone":["32 GB(4 GB RAM)","64 GB(4 GB RAM)"],"Discount:0%": ["15000", "1800"]},"Perfume":{"Unit:Quantity":["10","3"],"Fugo Perfume":["30ml","60ml"],"Discount:0%": ["300", "600"]}}

        self.inventr_gridbox = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.inventory_widget)

        self.table1 = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.table1.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus);
        self.table1.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget{gridline-color: white}")
        self.Inventory_scrollarea = QtGui.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        self.Inventory_scrollarea.setWidget(self.inventory_widget)
        self.Inventory_scrollarea.showFullScreen()

        self.table1.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.table_item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table1.setRowCount(21)

        self.table1.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table1.setColumnCount(7)
        stylesheet1 = "::section{Background-color:black;color: white;font-size: 25px;}"
        header1 = self.table1.horizontalHeader()
        vh1 = self.table1.verticalHeader()


        vh1.setDefaultSectionSize(50)
        header1.setResizeMode(0, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header1.setResizeMode(1, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header1.setResizeMode(2, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header1.setResizeMode(3, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header1.setResizeMode(4, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header1.setResizeMode(5, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header1.setResizeMode(6, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.table1.setColumnWidth(2,350)

        self.index = 0
        for key, value in self.inventory_dict.items():


            self.shrtlabel = QtGui.QPushButton()
            self.shrtlabel.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("./{0}.png".format(key)))
            self.shrtlabel.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{outline : None;}")
            self.shrtlabel.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40,60))
            self.table1.setCellWidget(self.index,0,self.shrtlabel)
            self.table1.setItem(self.index,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(key)))
            keys = value.keys()
            values = value.values()

            if len(keys) == len(values):
                self.table1.setItem(self.index,2,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(keys[0])))
                self.table1.setItem(self.index,3,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(keys[2])))
                self.table1.setItem(self.index,4,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(keys[1])))
                self.table1.setItem(self.index+1,2,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(values[0][0])))
                self.table1.setItem(self.index+1,3,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(values[2][0])))
                self.table1.setItem(self.index+1,4,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(values[1][0])))
                self.table1.setItem(self.index+2,2,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(values[0][1])))
                self.table1.setItem(self.index+2,3,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(values[2][1])))
                self.table1.setItem(self.index+2,4,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(values[1][1])))
                self.index +=3

        self.inventr_gridbox.addWidget(self.table1,1,0)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.Inventory_scrollarea)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    settingobj= Inventory_items()
    settingobj.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

here i want to show the borders for item only not the below description items

Comment: That seems to be a very strange thing to want to do. Why would you want to do that? Perhaps it would be clearer if you added a screenshot showing the effect you want to achieve.

Comment: sir just now i update the image please  check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your data is that of a tree so you should use a QTreeView or a QTreeWidget, and then you can set the border using a delegate:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class InventoryDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super(InventoryDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
        if not index.parent().isValid():
            painter.save()
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("green")))
            r = QtCore.QRect(option.rect)
            r.adjust(0, 1, 0, -1)
            painter.drawLine(r.topLeft(), r.topRight())
            painter.drawLine(r.bottomLeft(), r.bottomRight())
            painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        s = super(InventoryDelegate, self).sizeHint(option, index)
        s.setHeight(55)
        return s

class Inventory_Items(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Inventory_Items, self).__init__(parent)
        self.inventory_dict = {
            "Shirt": {
                "Men Solid Formal Blue shirt": ["10.10.1(Red)", "10.10.2(blue)"],
                "Discount:0%": ["300", "400"],
                "Unit:Quantity": ["10", "5"]
            },
            "Frocks": {
                "Baby Girls Partywear Frock": ["10.10.1(pink)", "10.10.1(black)"],
                "Discount:0%": ["900", "1200"],
                "Unit:Quantity": ["50", "30"]
            },
            "Shoes": {
                "Sparx Men's Running Shoes": ["Navy Blue", "Orange color"],
                "Discount:0%": ["2000", "2500"],
                "Unit:Quantity": ["100", "300"]
            },
            "Phones": {
                "Realme 2 Pro Smart phone": ["32 GB(4 GB RAM)", "64 GB(4 GB RAM)"],
                "Discount:0%": ["15000", "1800"],
                "Unit:Quantity": ["30", "10"]
            },
            "Perfume": {
                "Fugo Perfume": ["30ml", "60ml"],
                "Discount:0%": ["300", "600"],
                "Unit:Quantity": ["10", "3"]
            }
        }

        self.inventory_widget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(columnCount=7, 
            expandsOnDoubleClick=False,
            indentation=0,
            focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus,
            iconSize=QtCore.QSize(40,60))

        self.inventory_widget.setColumnWidth(2, 350)
        self.inventory_widget.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: black;color: white;}")
        header = self.inventory_widget.header()
        header.hide()
        header.setResizeMode(0, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setResizeMode(1, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setResizeMode(2, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setResizeMode(3, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setResizeMode(4, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setResizeMode(5, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setResizeMode(6, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        delegate = InventoryDelegate(self.inventory_widget)
        self.inventory_widget.setItemDelegate(delegate)

        for key, value in self.inventory_dict.items():
            icon = QtGui.QIcon("./{}.png".format(key))
            it = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
            self.inventory_widget.addTopLevelItem(it)
            it.setIcon(0, icon)
            k = list(value.keys())
            for i, t in enumerate([key] + k):
                it.setText(i+1, t)

            e = [[] for _ in value[k[0]]]
            for k, v in value.items():
                for i, val in enumerate(v):
                    e[i].append(val)
            for r in e:
                child = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
                for i, e_ in enumerate(r):
                    child.setText(i+2, e_) 
                    it.addChild(child)  
        self.inventory_widget.expandAll()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.inventory_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    settingobj= Inventory_Items()
    settingobj.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```